# saving data into two tables at the same time with a single form

Tags: python-3.x, django

I would like to save data in two tables at the same time using a single form in Django. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Stock(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)

class StockHistory(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is not saving the data you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two forms in a single view. It is not advised to save two different objects in a single modelform as it will get difficult to maintain and scale.
What you can do is create two different form and then in your template, load both the form inside a single `<form>` tag. Then inside your view you can check for the validity of both the forms and respond accordingly.

You can refer [here](https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/) for more explanation.

Edit:
in forms.py

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['item_name', 'category', 'quantity']

class StockHistoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['item_name', 'category', 'quantity']
```

in views.py

```
def your_view(request):
    stock_form = StockForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock_form = StockForm(request.POST)
        stock_history_form = StockHistoryForm(request.POST) #corrected here
        if stock_form.is_valid() and stock_history_form.is_valid():
            stock_form.save()
            stock_form_history.save()
            return HttpResponse("Saved")
    return render(request, 'your_html.html', {'form': stock_form})
```

Now you can render the form inside your template, and it will save both the objects with the same data.
If you need only the `item_name` field is same for the form then you can do this

in forms.py

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['item_name', 'category', 'quantity']

class StockHistoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['category', 'quantity'] //remove item_name from fields
```

in views.py

```
def your_view(request):
    stock_form = StockForm()
    stock_history_form = StockHistoryForm() //added this
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock_form = StockForm(request.POST)
        stock_history_form == StockHistoryForm(request.POST)
        if stock_form.is_valid() and stock_history_form.is_valid():
            stock = stock_form.save() //changes here
            stock_form_history.save(item_name=stock.item_name) //changes here
            return HttpResponse("Saved")
    return render(request, 'your_html.html', {'stock_form': stock_form, 'stock_history_form':stock_history_form}) //changes here
```

Then inside your HTML you can load both the forms under the same `<form>` tag.

Comment: Aakash, please I tried the above method but I got double HTML tags for the data field for the models. eg. the would be two item_name fields one for stock and one for stock history. But I want a situation where there would be only one item_name input field but when you enter data in it, it would populate the stock and stock history field of their respective model. Thanks

Comment: You can render only one of the forms if all of the data fields are same, or you can only include the fields which are not repeating. See the edit above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Aakash. I really appreciate your feedback and contribution.

Comment: Please why is the second table only record the primary key of the category id instead of the real value. As a result, when I'm trying to perform updates on the tables I get the error, Cannot assign "'1'": "Stock. category" must be a "Category" instance. Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this error and add the error response by making a edit in the question or creating a new thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659540/updating-two-models-with-a-foreign-key-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1#comment116089422_65659540

Comment: Please Aakash, find attached a link to the error I am talking about. Thanks