# Updating two models with a foreign key at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, django

Below are my codes and I get the error ValueError at /inventory/stock/1/edit
Cannot assign "'1'": "Stock.category" must be a "Category" instance.

in model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Stock(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)

class StockHistory(models.Model):
   category = CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)
```

in view.py

```
def UpdateStock(request, pk):
    stock = Stock.objects.get(id=pk)
    stock_form = StockForm(instance = stock)
    history_form = StockHistoryForm(instance = stock)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock_form = StockForm(request.POST, instance = stock)
        history_form = StockHistoryForm(request.POST, instance = stock)
        if stock_form.is_valid() and history_form.is_valid():
            stock = stock_form.save()
            history = history_form.save()
            return redirect('inventory')

    context = {
         'stock_form': stock_form,
          'history_form': history_form
     }

     return render(request, 'inventory/edit.html', context)
```

Comment: You should post your form.

Comment: Shouldn't the instance passed to `StockHistoryForm` be a `StockHistory` object?

Comment: The ValueError indicate that you are passing an integer in the Category ForeignKey field, you should pass the Category model based on the integer id that you are trying to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error are in save moment, for example:

```
stock_temp = StockModel.save(category=1) #can to generate error

stock_temp = StockModel.save(category=Categoty.objects.get(id=1)) 
#in this second case, stockcategoty IS a "Category" instance.
```

maybe you need post the code where are saving data.

You can see more here: [OneToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)